# What to do when PyCharm loads, is visible in TaskManager, but there is no window?

Tags: pycharm

I have an issue with PyCharm not starting properly.
No matter, how I open it, even as Admin:

Start from exe:

[image: start from exe]

It shows the loading screen for a couple of seconds:

[image: loading screen]

The icon in the taskbar flashes for a second, indicates an open window, but a window never opens. Or maybe it disappears again so quickly?

PyCharm is visible in TaskManger:

[image: PyCharm in TaskManager]

And afterwards just sits idle:

[image: PyCharm in TaskManager idle]

This issue suddenly started happening yesterday with the previous up-to-date installed version of PyCharm Professional. I then uninstalled it and installed the newest version. This is now PyCharm Professional 2021.1 - and the issue still persists. I restarted my machine multiple times in between, when the issue occurred, after uninstall, after reinstall.

I have no clue what to do about it, or where to look, since it is apparently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! It was due to a plugin supporting .proto files that caused the issue.
I deleted the JetBrains folder in C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local and C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming which deleted all the plugins and PyCharm configuration.
Now PyCharm starts again, but has to be newly set up and configured of course.